# Recommendation of Books of Survival Analysis

Tags: reference-request, statistics

I'd like a book of survival analysis at the undergraduate level. If it's self-contained, then that would be better. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

An epidemiologist recommended "Survival Analysis Using SAS - A Practical Guide", by Paul D. Allison.  While it illustrates examples with output from SAS code, I've found the explanations for the key concepts stand pretty well on their own.